# Managed CSOM on Sharepoint 201. Could not create SSL/TLS secure channel

Tags: ssl, sharepoint-2013, csom

I have a Windows Server 2016 VM and Visual Studio 2017 Community Edition. I am writing a simple script just to check the connectivity with the Sharepoint 2013. The Sharepoint Server is NOT installed on the VM, it is somewhere within the intranet.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.SharePoint.Client;
using System.Security;

namespace ConsoleApp1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string siteUrl = "https://xxx.yyy.org:443";
            ClientContext clientContext = new ClientContext(siteUrl);

            Web site = clientContext.Web;
            List documents = site.Lists.GetByTitle("Documents");

            //Prepare the request
            clientContext.Load(site);

            //Submit the Request
            clientContext.ExecuteQuery();

            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
}
```

But I am getting this exception:

> ## System.Net.WebException occurred
>
> > HResult=0x80131509
> >     Message=The request was aborted: **Could not create SSL/TLS secure channel.**
> >     Source=System
> >     StackTrace:
> >
> > > at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetResponse()
> > >       at Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.SPWebRequestExecutor.Execute()
> > >       at Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientContext.GetFormDigestInfoPrivate()
> > >       at Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientContext.EnsureFormDigest()
> > >       at Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientContext.ExecuteQuery()
> > >       at ConsoleApp1.Program.Main(String[] args) in C:\Users\AdminDD\source\repos\ConsoleApp1\ConsoleApp1\Program.cs:line

I've read this [thread](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/153265/csom-could-not-establish-trust-relationship-for-the-ssl-tls-secure-channel) and I signed in through IE. The certificate of the browser seems valid and the problem remains. Is there any suggestion on how to solve this ?

Answer (score 1):

I had the exact same issue. 
Check your project .Net Version. It worked after upgrading from 4.5 --> 4.6

Answer (score 0):

you should do a request on your url https://yoursite/ absolute url only, nothing more

```
$response = Invoke-WebRequest -Verbose -URI $anUrl -CertificateThumbprint $CertificateThumbprint -UseDefaultCredentials -SessionVariable websession -ErrorAction:Stop
```

get cookie authentification in reponse, and then add it in your csom query

```
$request.ClientCertificates.Add($global:cert)

$request.CookieContainer = New-Object System.Net.CookieContainer

$c3 = New-Object System.Net.Cookie($global:cookieName3, $global:cookieVal3, "/", $global:cookieDomaine);

$request.CookieContainer.Add($c3);
```

[here is a working sample](http://fdi-sharepoint.e-monsite.com/blog/powershell/csompowershellssl.html)